# ASP.net Application State

Tags: asp.net, state

I can store Session State in "InProc" or State Server or Sql Server. If i maintain
Application State where do objects are getting physically stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Application state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx) is stored in memory.  Every time the application is restarted, this is cleared out.

Because it is in memory, it cannot be used to store data accessible to a web farm.

Answer (score 0):

it is stored in memory on the server

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx)